# Filtro (filter) y Suma Columna (Footer Callback) DataTables

Tags: php, javascript, datatables

Se implementó el filtro individual por columna y además la suma de las cantidades de una de ella al pie de tabla. Funciona, pero cada que cargo las tablas me sale: **DataTables warning: table id=domingo2 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable**

He leído y la ayuda e indican que ese error es porque se a inicializado más de una vez #id.DataTable. Y sugieren utilizar una función destroy().

Tengo inicializado dos veces porque en una cargo el Footer Callback y en otra los filtros individuales. Si los junto en un solo llamado chocan y no funcionan ambas rutinas. La pregunta es, he revisado y no se como meter ambas rutinas en un solo llamado del DataTable para que funcione. El codigo es el siguiente:

1er LLamado con la rutina del Footer Callback (Total de la suma, columa)

```
$(document).ready(function() //TABLA PRELIBRO
    {
        $('#domingo3').DataTable(
        {
            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display )
            {
                // $(tfoot).find('th').eq(0).html( "Starting index is "+start );
                var api = this.api(), data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function ( i )
                {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
                };

                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column( 2 )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                // Total over this page
                pageTotal = api
                    .column( 2, { page: 'current'} )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );

                // Update footer
                pageTotal = Intl.NumberFormat('es-419').format(pageTotal); //CONVENTIR A MONEDA
                total = Intl.NumberFormat('es-419').format(total); //CONVENTIR A MONEDA
                $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(
                    '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' Monto Total)'
                );
            }

        });
    });
```

**2do Llamado colocando a la misma tabla los filtros individuales**

```
$(document).ready(function() //FILTRO TABLA PRELIBRO
    {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#domingo3 thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#domingo3 thead' );
        $('#domingo3 thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) 
        {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" style="float: center;" id="SearchTable2" placeholder="Filtro" />' );

            $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () 
            {

                if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) 
                {
                    table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
                }
            });
        });
        var table = $('#domingo3').DataTable(
        {
            orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true
        });
    });
```

Gracias, espero puedan apoyarme.

Answer (score 0):

Muy buen día:

La solución es más simple, leyendo la documentación llegue a la conclusión de que a mi código le falta una coma, esto se debe cuando se añaden más opciones al dataTable. Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
var table = $('#domingo3').DataTable(
        {
            orderCellsTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
        });
```

Para aquellos que tengan un problema similar, esta es la solución.